# Problem with "Unread Messages Count" in Mesibo Flutter SDK

Tags: flutter, dart, mesibo

I am trying to implement chat feature in flutter using `mesibo_flutter_sdk 2.2.4`. I'm trying to get the unread messsages count of each chat using `profile.getUnreadMessageCount()` and I get the number normally but when I read the message, the number of unread messages doesn't change.

The messages should be set to "READ" automatically but that doesn't happen with me.

Note that I'm not using `Mesibo UI`.

Comment: The getUnreadMessageCount function works correctly, it is used in mesibo UI too and hence should work for your custom UI too. Please note that you MUST post full code so that we can understand if you are using the function correctly or not. Please download sample code from the GitHub and reproduce the issue, and then post or send us the code and we will help you. https://github.com/mesibo/samples/tree/master/flutter/firstapp

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I created a sample app so you can undrestand my issue. I also want to know how exactly should mesibo know that I read the message from the custom chat? there's no indication for Mesibo that I got into chat. https://github.com/melsayed8450/Mesibo_sample_app